# AUI Datepicker & IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, datepicker, liferay, alloy-ui

Bit of a simple question but it seems that the AUI datepicker in Liferay (v.6.2 CE) just straight up does not work on IE, I've tried IE8, IE9, IE10 & Edge. (It just appears as a text entry input element with no ability to use the clickable popup displayed on other browsers)

Has anyone had any similar issues and what work arounds did you decide to go with? I hate the idea of having to use a new library like jQuery UI or importing a polyfill just because of this one silly element not working. Though if its the only solution its the only solution!

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

-Ash

[EDIT 1]

```
<aui:input label="cp-dob" name="sp_dob" type="date">
    <aui:validator name="date" />
</aui:input>
```

Comment: Could you show in a snippet how you've integrated the datepicker into your portlet?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke do you mean like my current edit with the code or do you want a screenshot? - Let me know if theres anything extra you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<aui:input type="date" />` does not have a built-in popup. The popup you are seeing in non-IE browsers is the [HTML5 `<input type="date" />` popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) (which is why it is different in different browsers). If you want a date input which pops up a calendar in all browsers, use `<liferay-ui:input-date />` which uses [AlloyUI's `DatePicker` component](http://alloyui.com/examples/datepicker/).